# s3cmd run on command line not on cron

Tags: cron, amazon-s3

Many have said that the problem is with environment but I still can't seem to solve this problem.
BTW I am using Ubuntu 9.10
login as user, then `sudo -s`
using this command: `s3cmd put file s3://bucket`      >>worked!
now here is the simple script intended for testing:

```
#! /bin/bash
env >/tmp/cronjob.log
```

> s3cmd put file s3://bucket

issuing the command `crontab -e`

```
* * * * * /opt/script  2>&1 | logger
```

Then using tail to syslogs

> Dec  3 23:22:01 ubuntu CRON[10795]: (root) CMD (/opt/script 2>&1 | logger)

But by verifying it on s3Fox Organizer, the file is not uploaded.

(I tried changing the `#! /bin/sh` (no effect), putting crons on `/etc/crontab` (no effect), setting `HOME=/home/user` (no effect)

What are other options to try? Or other ways to debug this problem.

Thanks

Comment: I also tried this /usr/local/bin/s3cmd put file s3://bucket (still no effect)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In my case it was missing configuration file (different env variables):

```
s3cmd -c /root/.s3cfg --no-progress -v put $TODAY_FILE $BUCKET  2>&1
```

If you will invoke your command like:

```
s3cmd command options 2>&1 | logger
```

You should be able to see in the logs real problem.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was to make sure `HOME` is set to the correct path. If you can run the command under user *joe* then your script should look like this:

```
HOME=/home/joe
s3cmd ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

`s3cmd put file s3://bucket`

to

`s3cmd put file s3://bucket > /tmp/s3cmd.log`

That way you can see what kind of problem s3cmd is having.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are referencing s3cmd using its full path (/usr/bin/s3cmd) in your script. Check that you have run s3cmd --configure as the user that cron will be running under, generally root.

Answer (score 2):

cron runs under `root user`, make sure your root user has s3cmd configuration otherwise copy them for root user

**cp -i /home/ubuntu/.s3cfg /root/.s3cfg**

Answer (score 0):

Check that `$HOME/.s3cfg` contains the access key and secret code for s3. If not, `s3cmd` will try to fetch them from the env variables which is different during cron session.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i tried to figure out why it is not running. My solution was to add the following lines to the top of my script:

`export HOME=/home/$USERNAME
cd /home/$USERNAME`

Also you should call the s3cmd with:

```
/usr/bin/s3cmd
```

OR put the following line to the top of your script:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```